# Singleton tooltip design in React

Tags: reactjs

Here is the case: I want to reuse a panel/callout/tooltip to display different content while I really do not want React to render multiple same DOMs. A code sample maybe look like below:

```
<SingletonTooltip />
<SingletonTooltip />
<SingletonTooltip />
```

And it will render 3 icons/buttons in the place I declare them but only renders one tooltip DOM when I click one of these icons/buttons.

A workaround I am not really into is:

```
<TooltipIcon />
<TooltipIcon />
<TooltipIcon />
...
<TooltipContent />
```

which brings extra effort to use and maintain code.

I have tried to save the instance in the state of component. However, this will make the component disconnected from the property passed by its parent.

Maybe React context will help? Looking forward to your guys suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make one component that renders all the buttons and then only renders one content element based off which one was clicked? let each button invoke an onClick handler which is given to it as a prop and then use this to render only what you need. if you implemented some global state management solution you could use even allow more elements place content into the content element

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I would like to know how could this component know where to render a button and where not to?